# how to configure log4j2.xml for non-spring projects

Tags: log4j2

I understand in spring projects, if we put the "log4j2.xml" under resources it will be picked up.

Mine is not spring project, but how do i configure "log4j2.xml" in java code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j looks for a file named log4j2.xml (or log4j2.yaml, log4j2.json, or log4j2.properties) on the classpath. If you are using Maven to build your project then placing the file in the src/main/resources directory will accomplish that.  If you want it to come from a different location you can set the log4j2.configurationFile system property before log4j starts and it will retrieve the file from that location. If you do not want to set a system property you can also use one of the initialize methods in Log4j's Configurator class.